# in keyword *SURFACE, file "FSECase1cor.inp", line 79025: Unknown assembly element set_M_SURF-1016_E3 (What does this error mean?)

Tags: finite-element-method, abaqus

I submitted the edited inp. file in abaqus. I edited the thickness of shell elements
then after I run the edited inp. file, I am suffering from this error.

Actually, there is another error:
"There are fewer than 2 items on a data line for which a generation sequence (start id, end id, optional increment number) is expected. The keyword in question is related to *ELSET. Please check input data"

does anyone know how to solve these error?

Comment: when programming / compiling etc, always correct the first error then re-compile : amazing how many errors can then disappear...

Comment: here the "other error" is likely the important one. Not much more to say unless you show the relevant part of the inp file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this problem.
I have made typing mistakes when editing the inp. file.
so it is highly recommended to write with high accuracy, otherwise, it can cause a lot of errors.